# Unable to initialise android driver using IP address(adb tcpip)

Tags: java, android, linux, selenium

Unable to initialise android driver using wifi connection. Always got org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException on connecting android mobile using adb tcpip port.

Initilaized tcpip port using given below shell commands.

```
 >> adb tcpip 5555
    restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

    >> adb connect 192.168.0.108:5555
    connected to 192.168.0.108:5555 

    >> adb devices
    List of devices attached
    192.168.0.108:5555 device 

    Started appium its listening on port 4723
```

Now i have tried to initialise android driver but it not working. Please help.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "");
capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.0.2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "vivo");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "test.package");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "test.activity");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 500000);

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.0.108:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Output:-

```
Dec 16, 2016 11:30:13 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'thangaraj', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
at initialize.Setup.initialize(Setup.java:238)
at script.ScriptRunner.setup(ScriptRunner.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And what about `Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.` Did you check

Comment: Issue due to invalid driver URL. After changing that works fine.